# Responsive 2 images over an other one image issues

Tags: css, media-queries, image-resizing

I have a problem with Responsive image... .
see my code:

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JozLmy**

```
img, embed, object, video{ max-width: 100%; 
height: auto}


.wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1180px;
    max-width: 99%;
}


#anatomy{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


#anatomy div.mainbody{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}

#anatomy div.brain{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 43px
}
#anatomy div.heart{
    position: absolute;
    left: 725px;
    top: 320px;
}
```

when I resize the browser window, I want to all three images resize together without changed the first position.

I point the position that I want to Image No.2 and 3 stay on that position, with white line.

before changing browser size:
[image]

after changing:
[image]

with the code I write on CodePen, just the pink picture resize and the others didn't resize and reposition... . :(

How can I solve this problem?

please help me... .

Comment: If your problem is the white line, you could always add a `border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;` or `outline-bottom: 1px solid #fff;` I assume it will stay on the bottomof your image and will respond on its width and position.

Comment: @GreenFox No. My problem isn't it. I draw the white lines on the ping image just to show the goal position that I want to other images stay on that position after resizing... .

Comment: I guess If you want to attach the images in a fixed position and you want to have responsive page it is inevitable to move the position when resizing.

Comment: @GreenFox the main idea is a human anatomy that in the main version, the ping image show a part of body and the two images are heart and brain. I want to show this three images correlative that when I resize the browser, this pack (three images) resize together. just it! :) Can you offer me another solution to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding `overflow:hidden` and changing `px` unit to `%` and set each `.brain` and `.heart` DIVs with `bottom`:
so,

```
#anatomy{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#anatomy div.mainbody{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}

#anatomy div.brain{
    position: absolute;
    width: 19.915254%;
    left: 25%; 
    bottom: 94%;
}
#anatomy div.heart{
    position: absolute;
    width: 12.288136%;
    left: 72.881356%; 
    bottom: 57%;
}
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are moving away from the white line because the images are positioned `absolute`ly. This means they are removed from the semantic flow of the document, and is [positioned relative to it's closest ancestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

The reason they are't moving when you resize your screen is because you have specified their position with a **fixed unit**, i.e. `px`. If you want your images to move and resize with the display, in true responsive fashion, you need to use flexible units, like a **percentage** i.e. `%`.

Apart from that, trying to position HMTL elements over the top of a static image is making things needlessly hard for yourself. Everything in that image can be achieved with CSS: [Here's the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timmah/7jna98xw/3/).

I'd recommend trying [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), as it features a code hilighter that shows when you've entered an invalid property, as I found a few in your code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I should give you a little description again.  in the fiddle version you create, I see you remove the ping image. I need this image. because in the main version, it's a part of human  body and the two images are heart and brain... . so I need it and I can't use CSS for create human body that I want to show... .
The white line on the ping image just a pointer to show when I resize the browser, I want to heart and brain images stay on that lines. just it. and I didn't  need this lines in the main version.. .

Comment: In that case, you could try using the `background-size` property on the CSS background images, to allow the image to scale with the screen, then use `%` instead of `px` to allow the hardcoded images to move proportionally?